# How to add multiple data tags to BufferedWriter?

Tags: php, android, web-services, post

my Android application uploads string data to a PHP webservice. This usually works if I restrict myself to one single datum. However, I'm in a situation where I need to identify different datasets in my PHP script.

This is what I try:

```
URL url = new URL("....script.php") // This is my webservice
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequest("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);

OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputSteramWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

writer.write("datum1=" datum1json.toString());
writer.newLine();
writer.write("datum2=" datum2json.toString());

writer.close();
outputStream.close();
...
```

My PHP script begins like that

```
if(isset($_POST['datum1']) && isset($_POST['datum2'])) {

$json1 = json_encode($_POST['datum1']);
$json2 = json_encode($_POST['datum2']);

echo $json1;
echo $json2; }
```

As long as I append one single datum to my writer (`writer.write("datum1=....`) and only test for one incoming variable in the php, everything works fine. In my case, I get an EOFException

```
java.io.EOFException
   at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
   ...
```

I do not suspect the PHP file, since it works with one set.

How do I attach two different datasets with identifiers to a writer?

I tried `writer.write("datum1=" datum1json.toString() + "datum2=" datum2json.toString());` too, but no success.

I know about different methods of POST requests (HttpDefaultClient,..) but I'm not too familiar with them and my requirements and data sizes are actually quite low.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
String datum1 = URLEncoder.encode(datum1json.toString(), "UTF-8");
String datum2 = URLEncoder.encode(datum2json.toString(), "UTF-8");

String params = "datum1=" + datum1 + "&" + "datum2=" + datum2;

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new OutputSteramWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(params);
writer.close();
outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!